# lvextend could be risky if volume is more then what is set

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm

as all know `lvextend` is the command that extend the size of a logical volume

as the following example

```
lvextend -L100G /dev/vg-test/lv_root
```

but this approach could be risky if the user by mistake also answered yes

for example

in case - `/dev/vg-test/lv_root` is already more then 100G for example **120G**

and if we do

```
 lvextend -L100G /dev/vg-test/lv_root
```

and answered `yes` on the question

then this can corrupted the volume and root file system cant be recover

so I want to ask if we can add some secured *syntax / flag*s to the following command

```
lvextend -L100G /dev/vg-test/lv_root
```

so even user enter yes it will not do anything

*Note - we not want to use the approach as lvextend -L+XXG*

Comment: What version of LVM are you using? Even with older version `lvextend` refuses to shrink an LV: `New size given (100 extents) not larger than existing size (125 extents)`, only `lvresize` asks for confirmation before shrinking.

Comment: what is the cli to check the LVM version?

Comment: `lvm version`, I tested the `lvextend` behaviour with CentOS 7 and `LVM version:     2.02.186(2)-RHEL7 (2019-08-27)`

Comment: lvm version
  LVM version:     2.02.130(2)-RHEL7 (2015-10-14)
  Library version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2015-10-14)
  Driver version:  4.33.0

Comment: so what you said about ?

Comment: For me it's `lvextend -L1G SSD/vm-ubuntu`, results in error message `New size given (16 extents) not larger than existing size (160 extents)`, **no questions**. `lvextend` only adds space, it should not be able to shrink it. `lvresize` goes in both directions and shrinking unintentionally can be lethal. Particularly on SSD or VM storage, with lvm.conf `issue_discards=1`, data is discarded immediately. On HDD you can recover with backups in `/etc/lvm/`...